# Why is .map() not returning anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically load a form from state after an API call, which is done in `componentDidMount()`. The API call is successful and `setState()` is called on `languageList` after it's done, but the `.map()` call does not return any options. It returns nothing.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let languages = []
    base('Languages').select({
      view: 'Grid view'
    }).firstPage(function(err, records) {
      if (err) {console.error(err); return; }
      records.forEach(function(record) {
        let languageObject = {}
        languageObject['id'] = record.id
        languageObject['name'] = record.get('Language Name')
        languages.push(languageObject)
      })
    })
    this.setState({
      languageList: languages,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <select>
        {this.state.languageList.map((language, key) => (
          <option key={key} value={language.id}>{language.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    )
  }
```

I've verified that `state.languageList` is an array of objects, each with an `id` and `name`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing wrong with snippet shown...issue lies elsewhere

Comment: Is this code *outside* the callback function for the API, or inside?

Comment: Have you checked `this.state.languageList`?

Comment: @Pointy Outside. Just updated the question a bit.

Comment: @iHowell yes. `this.state.languageList` contains a number of objects.

Comment: Still not enough known, need to show more code

Comment: in react it is advisable not to use the key provided by functions like map in listing. It is rather advisable to use the object's objectId which is very unique.

Comment: If it's *outside* the API callback, then the problem is that your `.map()` call is running before the API actually returns any content.

Comment: OK....problem is you need to call setState inside the api `firstPage` callback. You are calling it before the api has returned data

Comment: @Pointy updated with more code. Wouldn't it get run again when `render()` is called from `componentDidMount()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `setState` into the API callback....when the data has been made available

You are calling it before the data is received since it is asynchronous

```
base('Languages').select({
  view: 'Grid view'
}).firstPage((err, records) => {// arrow function to not block `this`
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  records.forEach(function(record) {
    let languageObject = {}
    languageObject['id'] = record.id
    languageObject['name'] = record.get('Language Name')
    languages.push(languageObject)
  })
  // languages array has been updated here
  this.setState({
    languageList: languages,
  })

})
```

Comment: Thank you thank you. Your comment `arrow function to not block this` was what I was missing. I had tried it but was hitting that error. :/ Can't thank you enough.

Comment: FYI - Had you mentioned the error we could have solved this fairly quickly

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select>
  {
   this.state.languageList && this.state.languageList.map((language, key) => (
   <option key={key} value={language.id}>{language.name}</option>
   ))
  }
</select>
```

Comment: Have to assume that `languageList` is always an array or would be error calling `map()`

Comment: Should I check array for null or undefined before call .map() like myArray && myArray.map()...?

Comment: @charlietfl in question the user is asking that  `I've verified that state.languageList is an array of objects, each with an id and name`

Comment: So I think @Jackkobec can assume that the variable is an array

Comment: @Sanaullah my point is the `&&` is pointless since it is always an array and will always be truthy

Comment: @charlietfl oh it is my misunderstanding

Comment: Thanks for answers. My question was about common situation, not about concrete this. If we know that variable is array, checking with && is unnecessary